# Given a $H(x)$ definite integral of $ f(t)$, determine $f$ and the constant knowing that is continuous

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals

Considering the function

$$H(x)= \int_{0}^{\pi\cdot x}f(t)dt=\frac{(2 \cdot \sin(\pi\cdot x)-\cos(2\pi\cdot x)+2\pi^2t+k)}{ 2}$$

determine $f$ and $k$ knowing that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

#### My steps(not sure if are right)

#### To get $f$:

$$H'(x)=\pi F'(\pi \cdot x)= \pi f(\pi x)\Rightarrow f(\pi x)=\frac{H'(x)}{\pi}$$
derivate
$$\frac{2 \cdot \sin(\pi\cdot x)-\cos(2\pi\cdot x)+2\pi^2t+k)}2$$
and I assume that this is a constant(not sure of this part), so when finish the derivate the result is:
$\pi (\sin(2 \pi x)+ \cos(\pi x))$ so when dividing by $\pi$ the final result is $(\sin(2 \pi x)+  \cos(\pi x))$
so

#### $f(\pi x)=\sin(2 t)+  \cos(t)$

#### to get $k$:

$$\frac{2 \cdot \sin(\pi\cdot 0)-\cos(2\pi\cdot 0)+2\pi^2t+k)}{ 2}=\frac{0-1+2\pi^2 t +k}{2}=0$$

so
finally $1+2\pi^2 t =-k$

Is right the procedure? seems strange for me that $k$ can't be resolved as a specific number (well is a number because for me this is a number not a variable, but not sure if is the right procedure anyway).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you really mean for the right-hand side of your $H(x)$ to have both $x$ and $t$ in it? I suspect the $2\pi^2\,t$ term should be $2\pi^2\,x$.

Comment: What's $sen$?​​

Comment: Is the letter of a previous examen,for me was extrange the t too ,sen is sin sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume $sen$ should be $\sin$ and the $2\pi^2t$ term should be $2\pi^2 x$. Then

\begin{align*}
H(x)&=\int_{0}^{\pi\cdot x}f(t)\,dt=\frac{2\sin(\pi x)-\cos(2\pi x)+2\pi^2x+k}{2}\\
H'(x)&=f(\pi\,x)\cdot\pi={2\pi\cos(\pi x)+2\pi\sin(2\pi x)+2\pi^2\over 2}\\
f(\pi\,x)&=\cos(\pi x)+\sin(2\pi x)+\pi.
\end{align*}

Taking $u=\pi x$, we see
$$
f(u)=\cos(u)+\sin(2u)+\pi.
$$

To find $k$, note that
$$
H(0)=0={-1+k\over 2}\implies k=1.
$$